# Is automation testing Black Box testing or White Box testing?

Tags: automated-testing, whitebox-testing, blackbox-testing

I came across this question & couldn't find a proper explanation anywhere. Can anyone clear this to me?

Comment: What do you mean by "automation testing"? The exploration of automated system and processes (e.g. Tesla assemble factory) looking for things that may affect their value?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean to ask about **Test Automation** as opposed to **Automation Testing**.

If I've got that right, I'd say it actually depends on what you are trying to automate.

If you are only automating the User Interface, for example, a user trying to log in to Gmail via a web browser or a the Gmail mobile app for that matter, then we can consider it a **Block-box Testing**. Although, if you consider accessing the HTML to get locators as white-box then as Mate Mrše mentions you can consider it as combination of both, Black and White box or as they have a term for it, **Hybrid Testing**.

If you are trying to automate an API or a database (for example, MySQL queries, stored procedures, etc.), mostly Unit Tests, then they would fall under the **White-box Testing** category according to me. As this would requires access to the backend and the actual code/database.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is *possible* for automation testing to be black-box but it seems unlikely if the automation is done by an in-house team. At least you will need access to HTML code (if we are speaking about web automation) for the locators. And the in-house team can always talk to the devs for details. In many cases, the one automating will be one of the developers.

On the other hand, it could be black-box if an outside team is automating with absolutely no access to the inner details of the code. Again, HTML is always accessible.

So, I guess, web automation is always at least partially **white box** because you need access to HTML locators.

Unit tests are usually automated and they are by necessity **white box**.